# Why does Option(null).map result in an error?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have defined a function as:

```
f:(Int)=>String
```

Why does the following result in error?

```
Option(null).map(f)
```

While the following just works fine?

```
None.map(f)
```

PS: `Option(null)` evaluates to `None` 
Edit: Following is the error I see on scala console

```
scala> Option(null).map(f)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int => String
required: Null => ?
   Option(null).map(f)
```

Comment: What kind of error? A compilation error? Please show the error text (by editing your post and adding it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `Option(null)` has type `Option[Null]`, while `None` is an instance of `Option[Nothing]`. `Null` is not a subtype of `Int`, but `Nothing` is.

`Option(null)` evaluates to `None` but that is not known at compile time. It doesn't make any sense to literally write `Option(null)` anyway. That construct is only useful when you're not sure whether the argument is `null` or not.